# Can you help me to get the integration of $\frac{1}{x} \exp(-x)$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I need the solution of integral like
$$\int^\infty_a \frac{1}{x} e^{-x} \,dx.$$

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of the exponential integral
$$
\int \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx=Ei(-x).
$$
Thus we can write
$$
\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx=-Ei(-a),\quad \Re(a)>0.
$$
There is nothing to prove, it is just definition of the function.  See here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral, where they write
$$
-\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx=Ei(x).
$$
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What magic is this!?

Comment: There is no magic:), it is the definition of the exponential integral.  @AlecTeal

Comment: What's E, is $i=\sqrt{-1}$? I'm going to call the other one "funky R" and I'm not sure what that is either. (I accept I just haven't seen this yet, help me learn!)

Comment: Ei is ExponentialIntegral.  The funky R means Real Part, see LaTex syntax.  @AlecTeal

Comment: I would have gone with $\frac{1}{x}=e^{\ln(\frac{1}{x})}=e^{-\ln{x}}$ then looked at $e^{-x-\ln(x)}=e^{-(x+\ln(x))}$...then gotten stuck. Hmm...

Comment: @AlecTeal Clever, however yes I agree then it is easy to get stuck with that integral.  However, we know now this is just the definition of the ExponentialIntegral (Ei).

Comment: This special function is probably defined in such a way because there **does not exist** a solution in terms of elementary functions. Also I like how the guy's name is "Integrals"

Answer (score 0):

This is a so-called exponential integral and cannot be put in closed form in general, see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) for example.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is exactly the Exponential Integral: $-Ei(x)$

You can look at it on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html). It doesn't looks like a integral that could be exactly solved.